# Matching websites in MySQL via regexp

Tags: mysql, regex

I have two columns: "website 1" and "website 2" and I want to test for equality. The issue is that there are differences in format such as:

```
www.example.com    http://www.example.com/
example2.co.uk/    https://www.example2.co.uk/Default.aspx
```

I would like to be able to match the domain only. Can this be done in MySQL given a regexp such as:

```
(http://|https://)?(www.)?[A-z]*(.com|.co.uk|.us|.org|.net|.mobi)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without RegEx,

TRY something like this to only take out the domain

```
SELECT 
(t1.website1, instr(reverse(t1.website1),'.')),
(t1.website2, instr(reverse(t1.website2),'.'))  
FROM table1 t1
```

Then you can check for equality on the domain.

You may also have to replace also the data from / and to end with nothing  in your select. Otherwise .aspx will be a domin in above case for instance.

You will also have to have a extra column that counts the amount of . , since some domains have 2 like .co.uk / .co.jp

like this

```
SELECT LEN('t1.website1') - LEN(REPLACE('t1.website1','.','')) AS AmountOfDotsInString
```

This gives you a count on how many dots exists in the string, do this count after the data after any / has been cleared.